# WPF with Entypo or other icon fonts

Tags: wpf, fonts, icons

I came across the [The Entypo Pictogram Suite](http://www.entypo.com/) and would like to use these as icons in my WPF app. I'm using .NET 4.5.

The pictograms are available in various formats, and I thought the easiest to include would be the open type font package.

After adding Entypo.otf as a resource in the project, I am able to get a TextBlock to show icons from the font like so:

```
<TextBlock Text="&#128260;" 
           FontFamily="../resources/#Entypo" 
           FontSize="48" 
           Foreground="DarkBlue"
/>
```

The rendering of the icon isn't great ... the main problem is that it appears the icons in this font are all "lower case" in the sense that the icon takes up half of the vertical space allocated for the `TextBlock` content.

Now I can more-or-less hack it to display properly by adding a negative top margin, but I'm thinking there might be a better way.

Is there a better way to use icon fonts, or would you advise some other solution altogether?

UPDATE

Maybe the best option is to use [Font Awesome](http://fortawesome.github.io/Font-Awesome/) ... it does not seem to have this "problem".

Comment: Wouldn't setting `LineHeight` be easier than using a negative margin?

Comment: Yes I think it probably would ... thanks for the idea ... will keep using font awesome for now since it doesn't require that kind of tinkering